# How do I create custom extensions on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

My team & I are building voice & video chat widgets using webrtc. We want to publish them as Firebase Extensions. This way all Firebase developers can simply add our extensions to get video and voice widgets on their web and mobile apps.

Is there a way to create & publish such custom widgets in Firebase? Are there any 3rd party companies doing so already? When I visit the [Firebase Extensions site](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions#explore), all I see is Google's own extensions. No 3rd party yet.

Are there any plans for google to open up Firebase extensions for other developers?

## AskFirebase #FirebaseExtentions #Firebase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The ability to create 3rd party extensions is under development, but is currently only available in early access. If you want to be notified of such early access features, join the [Firebase alpha program](https://firebase.google.com/alpha).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create & publish such custom widgets in Firebase?

Currently, no.

> Are there any 3rd party companies doing so already?

There are no extensions available that are not distributed officially by Firebase.  The extensions you see now are actually built by another company, but in cooperation with Firebase.

> Are there any plans for google to open up Firebase extensions for other developers?

You should ask this question directly to Firebase staff, not Stack Overflow.  I suggest posting to [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create & publish such custom widgets in Firebase?

Yes, now you have the ability to publish your own Extension inside the [Firebase Extensions Hub](https://extensions.dev/extensions).

> Are there any 3rd party companies doing so already?

Yes, there are already extensions that are not distributed only by Firebase.

If you want to create your own Firebase Extension, then please see the docs below:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/get-started